# How to load a Custom Java View class to a RelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-paint

I want load some Custom Views within my `RelativeLayout` but don't know how. The code I've tried doesn't work hence does anyone know how to do this correctly?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView0" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/drawing0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/drawing1"                
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/drawing0" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_below="@id/drawing1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/drawing1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView2" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView3" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView4" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Shapes.java**

```
public class Shapes extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public Shapes() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.shapes, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        //blue shape drawing
        View cv0 = (View)v.findViewById(R.id.drawing0);
        v.addView(new BlueShape(getActivity()));

        //green shape drawing
        View cv1 = (View)v.findViewById(R.id.drawing1);
        v.addView(new GreenShape(getActivity()));

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**BlueShape.java**

```
public class BlueShape extends View {
    private final Paint mBlue = new Paint();

    ...

}
```

**GreenShape.java**

```
public class GreenShape extends View {
    private final Paint mGreen = new Paint();

    ...

}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Where the error appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

specifically under

> **Modifying an Existing View Type**
>
> 4. Use the Custom Component

you can change the xml in your RelativeLayout

```
<View...
```

to

```
<your.package.GreenShape...
```

if you do not know beforehand what the View is going to be, then change it to

```
<FrameLayout... instead of <View...
```

and then add the child (GreenShape or BlueShape) programmatically to that Frame layout

Comment: I already did that but need to reuse the layout to show dozens of other different views hence doing that is not a good idea.

Comment: @MacaronLover   
does changing drawing0 and drawing1 from View to FrameLayout work? you need a layout to contain child views. also the BlueShape/GreenShape may have width and height of 0dp (hence it's not showing up)

Answer (score 1):

cv0, cv1 are not ViewGroup.
Try to change cv0, cv1 to ViewGroup and move onActivityCreated's code to onViewCreated callback method.

here is reference site.
[android/view/ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you are using `v.addView()` instead of

```
cv0.addView()
```

But I would suggest to use the following instead of your `View`:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawing1"                
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/drawing0" />
```

then, inside the Java code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout cv0 = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.drawing0);
    cv0.addView(new BlueShape(getActivity()), 0, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```